# Excel vba : Type range and cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am bit confused by cell and range in vba (excel).
Logically, i could think a cell as a range with size = 1; and I think it is easy to make a range out of a cell.

If I read the api of EntireRow property [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff836836.aspx)
it operates on range. But, the below code work, indicating 'cell'variable inside the loop is a range

```
Set import = Sheets("import")
    Set spRange = import.Range("A2")
    Set spRange = import.Range("A2:" & spRange.End(xlDown).Address)
    For Each cell In spRange
        dict.Add cell.Offset(0, 2).Text, cell.EntireRow
    Next cell
```

At the same time, the below code returns an error indicating type mismatch when call the **removecell** function. What should be the type of **targetCell** in the function definition?

```
Set spRange = mySheet.Range("b2", mySheet.Range("b2").End(xlDown))
For Each cell In spRange
    val = removecell (cell)
Next cell


Public Function removecell(targCell As Range) As Boolean
    removecell = False
End Function
```

Comment: You are right. Cell is a Range with 1 item. Is `val`, of type `Boolean`?

Comment: yes. this method was previously working when I passed "cell.Text", and accept it in the remove method cellVal As String. Now I am trying to pass the cell (range) itself by passing cell instead of cell.Text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This compiles and runs:

```
Sub Tester()
Dim spRange As Excel.Range
Dim cell As Excel.Range
Dim mySheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim val As Boolean

Set mySheet = ActiveSheet
Set spRange = mySheet.Range("b2", mySheet.Range("b2").End(xlDown))
For Each cell In spRange
    val = removecell(cell)
Next cell

End Sub

Public Function removecell(targCell As Range) As Boolean
    removecell = False
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks. "Dim cell As Excel.Range" gave me a clue, as I was not explicitly declaring cell before. As I mentioned, I just converted the method, and previously I didn't need to declare cell explicitly. The error I got was bit misleading.

Comment: The default value of the Range object is Value, so with Cell not declared as a Range, Cell was assumed to be a Value, which, reasonable enough, caused the "type mismatch."  It's very good practice to declare all variables.  To force this, in the VBE choose Tools>Options>Editor>Require Variable Declaration.  This will add Option Explicit to the top of all new modules, and give you a "Variable not Defined" compiler error for undeclared variables.  You can also just type Option Explicit at the top of existing modules.